# auth issues with angular and firebase, undefined is not a function, how to?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebasesimplelogin

i am trying to use the [firebase user authentication and management](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-user-authentication-and-management) to register, login, etc a user

but i have issues getting `$getAuth()` or `$createUser()`, they come in as `undefined is not a function`, also `$getCurrentUser()` seems to be missing

example:

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])

    .factory('Auth', function ($q, $firebase, FBURL, $location, $rootScope, localStorageService) {

        var ref = new Firebase(FBURL);
        var auth = $firebase(ref);

console.log(auth.$getAuth()); //undefined is not a function
```

any ideas?

i am using `AngularFire 0.9.0`, `Firebase v2.0.4`, `AngularJS v1.3.3`.

Comment: Are you sure `window.Firebase` exists?

Comment: What is the value of `FBURL`? Is it a string? You're injecting it as an angular service...

Comment: @AlienWebguy `FBURL = .constant('FBURL', 'https://xxxxxx.firebaseio.com/')`

Comment: `$getAuth` is supposed to only return a authData when the user is logged on. Is your user logged on? https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-user-authentication-and-management-getauth

Comment: Also note that the samples get to `getAuth` with: `$scope.authObj = $firebaseAuth(ref); var authData = $scope.authObj.$getAuth();`, while the snippet above seems to try and get it straight from `ref`. That will definitely not work, since `ref` is a regular Firebase API and doesn't have any of the AngularFire `$` methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have some copy/paste/modify errors from the examples. `$getAuth` is an AngularFire method, so it is not defined on a regulare Firebase JavaScript ref.

The simplest example I could quickly code up:

```
angular.module('app', ['firebase'])
  .constant('FBURL', "https://your.firebaseio.com")
  .factory("Auth", function($firebaseAuth, FBURL) {
    var ref = new Firebase(FBURL);
    return $firebaseAuth(ref);
  })
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, Auth) {
    $scope.auth = Auth;
    console.log(Auth.$getAuth());
  })
;
```

Note that this will only log something meaningful if the user is logged in, otherwise it will log `null`.

Comment: thanks, it seems that i had to refactor my `factory` to take advantage of new changes in angular fire and firebase